# Travis: run tests on PR merge ref

Tags: git, continuous-integration, travis-ci, pull-request

Every time a pull request is open, Github automatically creates a `refs/pulls/<PR_num>/head` and a `refs/pulls/<PR_num>/merge` refs.

The latter contains the result of the merge and is especially useful for e.g. CI (because what you want to test is actually the result of the merge).

I am wondering if there is an easy way to run tests on Travis on the `refs/pulls/<PR_num>/merge`, so I can test the result of the merge before it is actually merged.

Comment: There's a config option for that in the repo's option panel on Travis

Comment: What specifically are you referring to @набиячлэвэлиь ? I don't see an option.